# DataTrigger storyboard not firing WPF on PropertyValueChange

Tags: c#, wpf

So forgive me ahead of time if this has been answered before and I just haven't been able to see it for the life of me, but I have been searching for the past 4 hours with no avail.

I am trying to get a DataTrigger to fire on the change of a single bool property. The DataTrigger is to begin a storyboard that simply just adjusts the window size.

Here is the XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:SatisfactionsViewModel x:Key="SatisfactionsViewModel"/>
    <!--The storyboard animation-->
    <Storyboard x:Key="windowFadeUp">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Height)" Storyboard.TargetName="Satisfaction_Processing">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="171"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</Window.Resources>
<!--The Datatrigger that doesn't seem to work, probably my own stupidity-->
<Window.Style>
    <Style>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsWorkingOnStuff, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}" Value="true">
                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource windowFadeUp}"/>
                </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Style>
```

Here is the relevant C# from the ViewModel:

```
    private bool isWorkingOnStuff;

    public bool IsWorkingOnStuff
    {
        get { return isWorkingOnStuff; }
        set
        {
            if (value == isWorkingOnStuff)
            { return; }
            isWorkingOnStuff = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    //Other non-relative stuff
   //PropertyChangedEvent handler
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
   //Bunch of other stuff not related
   private void ProcessCommand()
    { 
        if (fileName == null || fileName == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please select a file. \nIt won't work without one... -_-");
        }
        else
        {
            IsWorkingOnStuff = true;
            IsProcessEnabled = false;
            IsProgressBarVisibile = Visibility.Visible;
        //more business logic goes here...
        }
   }
```

So as I understand it, when the IsWorkingOnStuff property changes to true, the datatrigger should fire, the storyboard execute, and rejoicing happen...but it's not.

Any idea where I am going wrong?

Thank you ahead of time.

Comment: What is "Satisfaction_Processing"?

Comment: Apologies. It's the name of the window:
`<Window x:Name="Satisfaction_Processing`'....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `Storyboard.TargetName` attribute and make sure that you have set the `DataContext` of the window to an instance of the `SatisfactionsViewModel` class:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="300" Width="300" x:Name="Satisfaction_Processing">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:SatisfactionsViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Window.Resources>
        <!--The storyboard animation-->
        <Storyboard x:Key="windowFadeUp">
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Height)">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="171"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Window.Style>
        <Style>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsWorkingOnStuff, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}" Value="true">
                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource windowFadeUp}"/>
                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Style>
    <StackPanel>

    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: That definitely pointed me in the right direction. I had an instance of the viewmodel made but just never set the WINDOW itself to have it. Soon as I did that: sunshine and rainbows.